# Tomcat version updated after EC2 instance clone

Tags: amazon-web-services, tomcat, amazon-ec2

I had a server A in ec2. I created an image, and launched a new server B (and setup b.domain.com to point to it. a.domain.com points to server A).

Immediately after the launch I see that the tomcat version in B is 7.0.82 while in A it's 7.0.73. How can this be? I didn't do any operation on the server after the launch, it was actually a careful reproduction of the issue that happened a while back.

I went to b.domain.com and saw this:

[image]

when I go to a.domain.com i see this:

[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47085576/tomcat8-is-being-reinstalled-while-creating-instance-from-custom-ami/47085799#47085799  This could solve your problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Tomcat8 is being reinstalled while creating instance from custom AMI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47085576/tomcat8-is-being-reinstalled-while-creating-instance-from-custom-ami)

Answer (score 1):

Most Amazon Linux AMIs are configured to install pending security updates on boot. If you rebooted the other instance Tomcat would update there also.

You should check your pending updates.

Comment: but i rebooted the existing instance many times since newer versions of tomcat were available... and how do I check it?

Comment: You you check it depends on the exact operating system you are using. What OS is running on them?

Comment: OP creating new instance from AMI, based on yum.conf settings, if new version of software is available in yum repo, while creating instance AWS automatically upgrading to newer version. Refer the link posted above for more information.

Comment: @kosa if it's an OS that uses `yum`. That's why I asked which OS they were using.

Comment: @MarkB Yes valid comment. My guess is yes, because I had similar issue starting a week ago.